# When submitting to the app store app gets declined because of crash

Tags: ios, crash-reports

So right now I have been submitting a app but whenever I submit it apple says

2.1 - Apps that crash will be rejected

2.1 Details

During review, your app crashed on iPhone running iOS 9 when we tapped on "Play"

This occurred when your app was used:

On Wi-Fi

On cellular network

Whenever I test my app with a real iPhone in Xcode it works perfectly fine 
They also attached a crash file for what happened.

[File for crash](http://a996.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple3/v4/1c/5e/19/1c5e1973-f8ff-5640-a80e-79921a3ed23e/temp..aidpfnoy.crash?downloadKey3=1444180477_97d6edda2609879007e609f6b45dcfae)

Please help me understand what has gone wrong with my application. I thank all of you that bothered to respond

Comment: You need to symbolicate that stack trace before you can understand it.

Comment: Using ad hoc testing: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html